# Why does table width:100% not work?

Tags: html, css

I need my Table to be width of 100%, but somehow the li has a width of 100% and the table ignores  the width of my li. How can I fix this? I looked through different posts about this problem and everywhere the solution is just like "set width to 100%", which obviously doesn't solve me problem..

Some more Info: I NEED the nowrap. Because this is a slider.

```css
table{
 width:100%;
 padding:20px;
 background:linear-gradient(rgb(230,57,18),rgb(170,32,11)); 
}
ul.table-wrap{
 overflow:hidden;
    list-style:none;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width:100%;
}
ul.table-wrap li.table-item{
 display:inline-block;
 width:100%;
}
table tr td{
 color:white; 
 vertical-align:middle;
 padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}
table tr td:nth-child(even){
 padding-right:30px;
 width:35%;
}
table tr td:nth-child(odd){
 width:15%;
}
table tr td:nth-child(2){
 border-right:1px solid white; 
 padding-right:10px;
}
table tr td:nth-child(3){ 
 padding-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="table-wrap">
<li class="table-item">
<table>
 <tr>
     <td>Kaufangebot: <td>Pflegeapartments nach dem Wohnungseigentumsgesetz(WEG)</td></td><td>Mietvertrag:<td>20-Jahres-Mietvertrag und 2 x 5 Jahre Verlängerungsoption</td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</li>
<li class="table-item">
<table>
 <tr>
     <td>Lage: <td>Karpfenstraße 11, 81825 München Einwohnerzahl: in Trudering ca. 66.000, in München ca. 1,4 Mio.</td></td><td>Mietbeginn:<td>April 2012 bzw. Juli 2014</td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please be so kind to explain why you are downvoting so the requester knows what the DO's and DON'Ts are.

Comment: Yeah I really don't get it right now...

Answer (score 2):

Because the padding also counts. Now your table is 100% (width) + 2x20px (padding)

Comment: The width of my Table is far bigger than 100% + 40px.

Comment: Yeah now I get it. Didn't see the lists in the first place

Answer (score 1):

It's because your `table` is contained in a `ul` `li` tag

You have to adjust the margin of your `ul` `li` to achieve the 100% width of the table.

**fixed your `td` tags

```css
table{
 width:100%;
 padding:20px;
 background:linear-gradient(rgb(230,57,18),rgb(170,32,11)); 
}
ul.table-wrap{
 width:100%;
    list-style:none;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

}
ul.table-wrap li.table-item{
 float:left; 
 width:100%;
}
table tr td{
 color:white; 
 vertical-align:middle;
 padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}
table tr td:nth-child(even){
 padding-right:30px;
 width:35%;
}
table tr td:nth-child(odd){
 width:15%;
}
table tr td:nth-child(2){
 border-right:1px solid white; 
 padding-right:10px;
}
table tr td:nth-child(3){ 
 padding-left:10px;
}
table table tr:last-child td{
 padding-bottom:0;
 border-bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="table-wrap">
<li class="table-item">
<table>
 <tr>
        <td>Kaufangebot: </td>
        <td>Pflegeapartments nach dem Wohnungseigentumsgesetz(WEG)</td>
        <td>Mietvertrag:</td>
        <td>20-Jahres-Mietvertrag und 2 x 5 Jahre Verlängerungsoption</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</li>
<li class="table-item">
<table>
 <tr>
        <td>Lage: </td>
        <td>Karpfenstraße 11, 81825 München Einwohnerzahl: in Trudering ca. 66.000, in München ca. 1,4 Mio.</td>
        <td>Mietbeginn:</td><td>April 2012 bzw. Juli 2014</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Didn't you just put away the ul?

Comment: My bad, pasted the wrong snippet. Updated now.

Comment: The default margin for the li tag is 40px by the way.

Comment: Now you put away the white-space:no-wrap... I need it to be no-wrap.

Comment: Still works with no-wrap.

Comment: It doesn't. Now it's neither 100% width, nor display:inline.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63467/discussion-between-mike-ante-and-frederik-witte).